# How to convert string dates in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, date

I'm working with a SharePoint list and it's common date/time format is
*2020-01-06T08:09:00.0000000Z*. I have source date that I'm writing to that list that's in another format, i.e. *11.07.2012 09:40*.

How can I convert that string into the format that the SharePoint list expects?

Closest I've come is:

`[datetime]$dateToConvert = "11.07.2012 09:40"
Get-Date -Date $dateToConvert -Format FileDateTimeUniversal`

which outputs `20121107T0840000000Z` but that's missing the dashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `-Format o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: `$dateToConvert.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")`

- ToUniversalTime() to get the "Z" at the end (instead of the UTC offset)
- ToString("o") to get a string that complies with ISO 8601

Comment: This doesn't work with PS 5.1, is this a new feature i PS 6.0?

Comment: @MokiTa Might be your `.Net` that is out of date. Here is the Microsoft documentation for `ToUniversalTime()` [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Putting `[datetime]` in front of the variable makes it work for me.